# When receive Array / Dictionary from Firebase

Tags: json, firebase

I have a storage for a community set up in Firebase. As I have a class defined in my Swift project I need to to know whether it´s an Array or a Dictionary when generating an object from it.

I downloaded the json File and it looks like this - 2 users are stored in different data formats in firebase for the same "table":

```
[{"user": {
    "User1": {
        "adminOf": {
            "3": true,
            "5": true
        },
        "alias": "borussenpeter",
        "communities": {
            "3": true,
            "5": true
        }
    },
    "User2": {
        "adminOf": [null, true, true, null, true],
        "alias": "burkart",
        "communities": [null, true, true, null, true]
    }
}}]
```

I tried downloading the file, edit it so both users are looking the same and uploaded it again, but Firebase saves it again this way.

Of course initialising the object fails when using the wrong data type. Any thoughts on that? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [Firebase documentation on arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase):

> However, to help developers that are storing arrays in a Firebase database,... if the data looks like an array, Firebase clients will render it as an array. **In particular, if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values**, then Firebase clients will render it as an array.

In the JSON for User1 you have 2 values (3 and 5) for 5 indices. That is less than half of the keys, so Firebase doesn't render it as an array.

In the JSON for User2 you have 3 values (2, 3 and 5) for 5 indices. That is more than half of the keys, so Firebase renders it as an array.

A few ways to deal with this:

- prefix the integers with a string, e.g. `"group3": true`.
- add a dummy non-integer to the "array": e.g. `"NOTUSED": false`.
- store values for all indices: e.g. `"group0": false`

Comment: My preferred way of fixing this is adding the following key and value: `renderAsArray: false`. It's still a hack, but it feels more like a feature. :)

Answer (score 2):

In general:

[ ] = array

{ } = dictionary

Answer (score 0):

How the data appears in Firebase is directly related to how it was stored in Firebase.

My guess is that when user 2 was written to firebase, the keys were missing so it wrote them as an array.

Comment: I guess export, edit, import would then fix this issue?! I tried but didn´t work.